# draw datframe after suming on a period

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe structured like this (much bigger in reality):

```
    location    dt_date        people
1   A           2021-02-22      5
2   A           2021-02-25      15
3   A           2021-03-02      11
4   A           2021-03-05      13
5   B           2021-02-23      2
6   B           2021-02-28      22
7   B           2021-03-03      1
8   B           2021-03-04      14
9   B           2021-03-10      6
10  B           2021-03-11      3
```

I want to draw the sum of people by week for location B.
Here what I did:

```
d_b_w=pd.DataFrame()
  d_b_w['p_sum']=df[df.location=='B'].people.groupby(df[df.location=='B'].dt_date.dt.to_period("W")).sum()
```

Then I can plot it with

```
d_b_w.plot()
```

But if I try to plot it with:

```
plt.plot(d_b_w.index,d_b_w.p_sum)
```

I have the following error:

```
ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

I don't understand why?

Thank you

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, but it probably comes from using `periodIndex` resulting from the `groupby`. when doing `d_b_w.plot()` there is probably a conversion happening in the implementation of the method that allows the plotting. While using `plt.plot` it raises an error as not the right type of data for the index. In the `groupby`, instead of getting the period, try with `df[df.location=='B'].dt_date - pd.to_timedelta(df[df.location=='B'].dt_date.dt.dayofweek, unit='d')` that bring any dates to the Monday before. same aggregation, different type in the index and the plt.plot should work

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `matplotlib` not playing well with `pandas` datetime.  You can coerce `matplotlib` to try to interpret `pandas` dates using [`plot_date()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date.html), but it will clearly involve more cleanup and styling:

`plt.plot_date(d_b_w.index, d_b_w.p_sum)`

[image]